# Why do we need to first convert to bytes then string when specifically decoding base64string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

Consider the following method:

```
private (string email, string password) GetCredentials()
    {

        string head = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (head == null || !head.StartsWith("Basic ")) throw new TokenValidationException("Token absent.");

        AuthenticationHeaderValue authHeader = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(Request.Headers["Authorization"]);

        if (!authHeader.Scheme.Equals("Basic")) throw new AuthenticationException();

        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Parameter);
        var header = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

        var parts = header.Split(new[] { ':' }, 2);
        return (parts[0].ToLowerInvariant(), parts[1]);
    }
```

Why do we need to do get the bytes first, then decode those to a UTF8 string?

Comment: *to a UTF8 string?* No, **from** *a UTF8 string*.

Comment: A Base64 string represents encoded bytes, these bytes can come from anything - a string, an image, an audio file, an executable etc.  When you decode you get the bytes back, its then up to you to decide how to further interpret them.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can store *any BLOB* as base-64 - it doesn't need to be a string. It could be a protobuf payload, an image, a file attachment, etc. In fact, usually when you're using base-64 it is *because* you want to store a binary payload in a text protocol; if you only wanted to store a `string`, you'd just... *embed the string directly*. So: it is *almost never* actually a string payload, hence why there's no `DecodeBase64ThenDecodeThatAsString` method.